# How to set numba signature with nested lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numba, numba-pro

I'm trying to return an nested list, however running into some conversion error.
Below is small piece of code for reproduction of error.

```
from numba import njit, prange

@njit("ListType(ListType(ListType(int32)))(int32, int32)", fastmath = True, parallel = True, cache = True)
def test(x, y):
    a = []
    for i in prange(10):
        b = []
        for j in range(4):
            c = []
            for k in range(5):
                c.append(k)
            b.append(c)
        a.append(b)
    return a
```

Error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid using empty lists with numba, mainly because an empty list cannot be typed. Check out `nb.typeof([])`

I am not sure whether your output can be preallocated but you could consider arrays. There would also be massive performance benefits. Here is an attempt:

```
from numba import njit, prange, int32
import numpy as np

@njit(int32[:,:,:](int32, int32), fastmath = True, parallel = True, cache = True)
def test(x, y):
    out = np.zeros((10,x,y), dtype=int32)
    for i in prange(10):
        for j in range(x):
            for k in range(y):
                out[i][j][k] = k
    return out
```

That said, you might indeed need lists for your application, in which case this answer might not be of much use.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I can't use numpy array as out, because of varying size of c.

Comment: Understandable. My hunch is, even if you could make signatures work somehow, the performance of the whole thing might be worse than a python only implementation. if you know the max size of your elements in each level maybe you could preallocate for that and fill the rest with np.nan?

Comment: You can initialize an empty but typed `List` with `List.empty_list(<type>)`, or alternatively use a 0-size list comprehension like `empty_f32 = [np.float32(x) for x in range(0)]`. That last one only works when inside a jitted function.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```py
from numba import njit, prange
from numba.typed import List

@njit(fastmath = True, parallel = True, cache = True)
def test(x, y):
    a = List()
    for i in prange(10):
        b = List()
        for j in range(4):
            c = List()
            for k in range(5):
                c.append(k)
            b.append(c)
        a.append(b)
    return a
```

Comment: do you have any info on how it performs?

Answer (score 0):

Your signature is fine, but you need to match the type of List that you create inside the function. So a `numba.typed.List` instead of `[]`.

```py
from numba import njit, prange
from numba.typed import List
from numba.types import int32

@njit("ListType(ListType(ListType(int32)))(int32, int32)", fastmath=True, parallel=True, cache=True)
def test(x, y):
    a = List.empty_list(List.empty_list(List.empty_list(int32)))
    for i in prange(10):
        b = List.empty_list(List.empty_list(int32))
        for j in range(4):
            c = List.empty_list(int32)
            for k in range(5):
                c.append(int32(k))
            b.append(c)
        a.append(b)
    return a
```

I don't think you should expect much from appending to a List in parallel in this case.